# spam avoiding mx records

Tags: email, spam, mx-record

I have some problem with spam. Sometimes we receiving emails directly to server when they should been send by MX records to spam filter. And in almost all cases is like this.
Normal email
sender->MX->spam filter->server

spam

sender->server

also they using/displaying sometimes our email address.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Why's your mail server open t the world, when, presumably the spam filter should be the only one passing it messages?

Comment: It does sound like your issue would be fixed by only allowing flows you actually want (i.e. spam filter -> server), and dropping everything else. Assuming your spam filter is correctly set up, it should be able to deal with your other issues (you might also want to create some SPF records).

Answer (score 4):

Just firewall your server to only allow incoming mail from the spam filter.